# (Unity) How do I save/load a party's stats?

Tags: unity-game-engine, save

I'm stumped in trying to save that. I had previously managed to save stats normally like this:

However I'm not sure how to handle it for when there are multiple characters (or when I have to save stuff like inventory data or other miscellaneous flags, for that matter). I'm thinking of using, say, lists, but then I don't know how to load them to each character, since I'm thinking of adding party members as the game goes on.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DataJson
{

    public int wp;
    public float spe;
    public Vector3 pos;

    public DataJson(Player play)
    {
        wp = play.WP;
        spe = play.spe;

        pos = new Vector3();
        pos.x = play.transform.position.x;
        pos.y = play.transform.position.y;
        pos.z = play.transform.position.z;
    }

}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public static class SaveJson
{
       
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public static void Save(Player player)
    {
        DataJson data = new DataJson(player);
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(data);
        File.WriteAllText(Application.dataPath + "/save.txt", json);
        Debug.Log("Saved");
        Debug.Log(json);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public static void Load(Player player)
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + "/save.txt");
        DataJson data = JsonUtility.FromJson<DataJson>(json);
        Debug.Log("loaded from: "+json);
        player.WP = data.wp;
        player.spe = data.spe;
        player.position = data.pos;
        player.transform.position = player.position;
    }
    public static void SaveTemp(Player player)
    {
        DataTemp data = new DataTemp(player);
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(data);
        File.WriteAllText(Application.dataPath + "/temp.txt", json);
        Debug.Log("Saved");
        Debug.Log(json);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public static void LoadTemp(Player player)
    {
        string path = Application.dataPath + "/temp.txt";
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + "/temp.txt");
            DataTemp data = JsonUtility.FromJson<DataTemp>(json);
            player.WP = data.wp;
            player.spe = data.spe;
            Debug.Log("Data WP: " + data.wp + "Data Spe: " + data.spe);
            File.Delete(Application.dataPath + "/temp.txt");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("nothing");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So ist your question about an implementation issue or rather a design decision? Note that the first requires a concrete implementation code and information about what exactly is expected and what is happening instead and the second is off-topic here on StackOverflow ...

Comment: The Inventory in the question or other things for that matter can easily be [ScriptableObject/s](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html). A very good tutorials related to these can be found at [Unity Unite Los Angles by Richard Fine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raQ3iHhE_Kk) and [Unity Unite Austin by Ryan Hipple](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raQ3iHhE_Kk)

Answer (score 0):

How I implement save / load in my RPG is that I assign an ID to each object i'm going to save.

So if I want to save some random crates throughout the level, one might have the ID of 'crate1', another as 'crate2' etc. Naming doesn't really matter, as long as they are unique. Then I save this id into the individual save data, and I have many individual save datas in an array.
Now whenever I load a save file, I just compare ID's to see who the data belongs to.

Psuedocode:

```
for each savedata in savedataArray
    Find character with the same ID
       Load Data onto the character
```